# "VolumeFailedDelete" error in the k8s cluster provided by docker-for-windows

Tags: kubernetes, volume, docker-for-windows, docker

I created a PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

Since the PVC doesn't specify a storage class, it will use the default storage class of the cluster. For my cluster, it is **hostpath**:

```
 $ kubectl get sc

    NAME                 PROVISIONER          AGE
    hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath   47d
```

The ReclaimPolicy of this sc is **Delete**. But still, when i remove the pvc, pv is not deleted. There is an error deleting the volume:

```
$ kubectl describe pv

Name:            pvc-eb128563-97fa-11e9-8f00-00155d380109
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by=docker.io/hostpath
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    hostpath
Status:          Released
Claim:           default/myclaim
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
Capacity:        8Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /host_mnt/c/Users/Anjana/.docker/Volumes/myclaim/pvc-eb128563-97fa-11e9-8f00-00155d380109
    HostPathType:
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age              From                                                                     Message
  ----     ------              ----             ----                                                                     -------
  Warning  VolumeFailedDelete  7s (x7 over 1m)  docker.io/hostpath DESKTOP-SRHMA82 87a9c372-97ca-11e9-bdd7-00155d38010b  persistent volume path is not prefixed by C:\Users\Anjana\.docker\Volumes
```

Why this happens? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Basing at the error you receive

> persistent volume path is not prefixed by
>   C:\Users\Anjana.docker\Volumes

And looking through the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#persistentvolumespec-v1-core):

> pathPrefix is the path prefix that the host volume must match. It does
>   not support `*`. Trailing slashes are trimmed when validating the path
>   prefix with a host path. Examples: `/foo` would allow `/foo`, `/foo/`
>   and `/foo/bar` `/foo` would not allow `/food` or `/etc/foo`

You should check if the path is configured properly in your pv yaml spec.

```
  hostPath:
    path:
```

EDIT:
Also `Finalizers: [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]` It means that your PV is protected. You can change that by setting finalizers to `null`

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: I have already added the details of PV in the question. Host path is set as `/host_mnt/c/Users/Anjana/.docker/Volumes/myclaim/pvc-eb128563-97fa-11e9-8f00-00155d380109`

Comment: Try something like this: 
`/c/Users/Anjana/.docker/Volumes/myclaim/pvc-eb128563-97fa-11e9-8f00-00155d380109`

Comment: Where should I specify that path? Actually, this PV path is automatically set by the default storage class. The volume should be deleted with the PVC automatically just like how it was created with PVC.

Comment: I just saw another thing here:
`Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]`
It means that your PV is protected. You can change that by setting finalizers to `null`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.

Warning      VolumeFailedDelete         persistentvolume/pvc-888e0eed-a795-11e9-8838-00155d9d5106   persistent volume path is not prefixed by C:\Users\user.docker\Volumes

Volume is created via PVC, hostPath is (automatically) set to that 
/host_mnt/c/Users/user/.docker/Volumes/myclaim/pvc-eb128563-97fa-11e9-8f00-00155d380109